# Libs add dependency android

Tags: android, module

I'm facing an issues about import aar file, which compile another one, and IDE request compile them also. 
Here is my problem:
I create a module, it's "mylibs". Mylibs compile another one. In my case is timber (libs about logging). 
Then i create a aar file from Mylibs and import it in mainProject by below code:

`compile(name: 'mylib', ext: 'aar') {
        transitive = true
    }`

After rebuilt, IDE request me must be import timber also. 
I dont understand why i need import timber lib ?

Answer (score 0):

`aar` files do not include dependencies. If they are shipped through a repository, there usually is a `pom` file in the same repo which describes the dependencies. In this case gradle can resolve transitive dependencies automatically.

But if you ship an `aar` locally, there are no informations on dependencies available, so you have to include them manually.